# Check the text of a page of a website isn't working properly

Tags: javascript

I've written a code to check the page of a website every second, but I think I did something wrong because it only gets the number the first time the function is called. After that, every other function called gets the same number over and over again, even if the number on the actual page changes. What am I doing wrong?

```
checkPage();

function checkPage() {

var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var text = html.innerHTML;
var matches = text.match(/Numbers \(([0-9]+)\)/);
console.log(matches[0]);
setTimeout(function(){ checkPage() }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Why would the text of the page change after it's loaded? Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Works for me: https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/pozGXNd?editors=1111

Comment: @j08691 Well, for example, if there's 100 shoes on sale on a website, and someone clicked buy, there would be 99 shoes left, but my script only gets the number of the shoes the first time the function is called. After that it gets the same number over and over again, no matter how many shoes are left.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Yeah, only if the number doesn't change.

Comment: Assuming you don't own the page and that it's not updated live (i.e. you have to refresh the page to view the new text'), then you should look into making HTTP GET requests every n seconds.

Comment: @junvar Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the HTTP GET function and now it works.

```
function httpGet(theUrl) {
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.send( null );
return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

checkPage();
function checkPage() {
var text = httpGet("https://example.com");
var matches = text.match(/Numbers \(([0-9]+)\)/);
setTimeout(function(){ checkPage() }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to call the function with `setInterval(checkPage, 1000);` not inside the function.